# How to download structure (.cif) file from materialsproject.org using python

Tags: python

I want to download cif file from https://next-gen.materialsproject.org using python. I used the following code

```
from pymatgen.ext.matproj import MPRester

# Initialize MPRester with your Materials Project API key
mpr = MPRester("*********")

# Specify the Materials Project ID (MPID) of the material you want to download the CIF for
mpid = "mp-165"  # Example: Si crystal

# Download the structure corresponding to the MPID
structure = mpr.get_structure_by_material_id(mpid)

# Write the structure to a CIF file
cif_filename = f"{mpid}.cif"
structure.to(fmt="cif", filename=cif_filename)

print(f"CIF file downloaded and saved as {cif_filename}")
```

When I run this code it says "Response {"error": "You are using deprecated API endpoints. Please read our documentation (https://docs.materialsproject.org) and upgrade to the latest version of the mp-api client (https://pypi.org/project/mp-api/).", "version": "blocked"}
".

It seems materials project website updated their API. I tried the new API as well using the code given in their website (https://docs.materialsproject.org/downloading-data/using-the-api/examples):

```
from mp_api.client import MPRester

with MPRester("your_api_key_here") as mpr:
    docs = mpr.materials.summary.search(material_ids=["mp-149"], fields=["structure"])
    structure = docs[0].structure
    # -- Shortcut for a single Materials Project ID:
    structure = mpr.get_structure_by_material_id("mp-149")
```

However I am still getting the same error. I am using python 3.8.10.